# strange behaviour when using jquery ui dialog from a success callback of ajax

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am trying to develop a jquery plugin that extend the ui dialog with some additional features I need for my site. One additional option is to pass an url (either for some html content, either for an iframe).  In total I have defined 13 options for my application. One strange behaviour is that when I call the dialog() method within a callback (the ajax loading the content into an element yet created, but not yet visible), it creates not 1 but 13 dialog box !!!

Here is the code (I cut the unnecessary code; the updater plugin allows to directly load the html content into an element, I keep it here, but that)

```
jQuery.fn.isset = function(){return this.length>0;}
jQuery.fn.updater = function() {
    var e = this;
    [...]
    options.url         = options.url           || url
    [...]
    $.ajax(options).success(function(data){e.html($(data);});

}; 
jQuery.bzkModal = {
    show :function(content,options){
        options = options ? options : {};
        $j.extend(true, options, {
            modal       : true,
            onClose     : options.onClose   || function(){},
            onOpen      : options.onOpen    || function(){},
            onShow      : options.onShow    || function(){},
            evalScripts : typeof(options.evalScripts)=='boolean' ? options.evalScripts : true,

            /* additional options */
            type : (options.type=='iframe') ? '<iframe>' : '<div>',
            maxHeight   : options.maxHeight || jQuery(window).height() * 0.9,
            maxWidth    : options.maxWidth  || jQuery(window).width() * 0.9,
            width       : 'auto',
            height      : 'auto',
            autoResize  : true,
            position    : options.position  || { my: "center", at: "center", of: 'body' },
        });

        if($('[id="'+content+'"]').isset())  {
            /* just do the standard dialog with options */
            $j('[id="'+content+'"]').dialog(options);
        }   
        else {
            /* create a DOM element */
            var f = $j(options.type);
            /* get content */
            if(options.type=='iframe') {
                [...]               
            }
            else {
                f.updater({url: content, success: function(){
                    f.dialog();
                }});
            } 
            /* if f.dialog(options) here, it works!!! */
        }
    },
        [...]
};
```

If I call the f.dialog(options) after the updater, it works, and I have only one dialog pox opened (only, as the dialog box is created before the html content is injected, I have problems with size and positionning of the dialog box).

Does anybody have an idea why I can have this strange thing (13 box opened, as much as I have defined options...) ?

I hope my question is comprehensive and I gave enough details.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the problem was coming from the updater. with the following, it works :

```
jQuery.bzkModal = {
    show :function(content,options){
        [...]
        if($('[id="'+content+'"]').isset())  {
            /* just do the standard dialog with options */
            $('[id="'+content+'"]').dialog(options);
        }   
        else {
            /* create a DOM element */
            var f = $(options.type);
            /* get content */
            if(options.type=='iframe') {
                [...]               
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({url: content, evalScripts: options.evalScripts})
                .success(function(data){ f.html(data).dialog(options); });
            }
        }
    },
    [...]
};
```

Tough, I don't understand where was the problem.